# Field extensions that preserve given cohomology classes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, arithmetic-geometry, reductive-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\operatorname{Ker}^1(\mathbb{Q},G) \subset H^1(\mathbb{Q},G)$ be the subset of classes that are trivial at all places. I am trying to understand the map $\operatorname{Ker}^1(\mathbb{Q},G) \to \operatorname{Ker}^1(F,G)$ where $F$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$.

**Question 1** Is it possible to write down sufficient conditions on $F$ for the map $\operatorname{Ker}^1(\mathbb{Q},G) \to \operatorname{Ker}^1(F,G)$ to be injective?

This question can be reduced to the case when the derived group is simply connected using $z$-extensions, and from there to the case when $G$ is a torus $T$.

One might guess that it should be enough that $F$ is linearly disjoint
from a fixed Galois splitting field $K$ of $T$. However it turns out that things cannot be so simple: If $\mathcal{P}$ is a nontrivial $T$-torsor over $\mathbb{Q}$ which has a $\mathbb{Q}_v$-point for all places $v$ of $\mathbb{Q}$, then a theorem of Moret--Bailly (see e.g. Proposition 3.1.1. of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.2561.pdf) tells us that there is a finite extension $F$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ linearly disjoint from $K$ such that $\mathcal{P}(F) \not=\emptyset$.

I am moreover interested if we can always produce an $F$ for which the restriction map on $\operatorname{Ker}^1$ is injective with prescribed local behavior. The most optimistic form would be:

**Question 2** Fix a prime $p$ and an integer $d \ge 1$. Is it always possible to find a totally real $F$ such that $$\operatorname{Ker}^1(\mathbb{Q},G) \to \operatorname{Ker}^1(F,G)$$ is injective and such that the extension $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic of degree $d$, everywhere tamely ramified, and such that $p$ is inert in $F$?

Comment: You can reduce your question to a question about complexes of tori using Theorem 5.11 of [Memoirs of the AMS 132 (1998), No. 626](https://www.tau.ac.il/~borovoi/papers/galofile.pdf).

Comment: To deal with complexes of tori, you can use  the paper by Cyril Demarche, 
Suites de Poitou-Tate pour les complexes de tores à deux termes. Int. Math. Res. Not. IMRN 2011, no. 1, 135–174.  See also https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3453.

Comment: You can try to try to answer your question for *semisimple groups* using calculations of $H^2$ with coefiicients in certain finite abelian algebraic groups in Sections 1 and 2 of  [Sansuc's paper](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002198746). Good luck!